# Should I split a single table with an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY into two tables that can be joined on that PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 46 fields with an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY.  It's hard to look at a table that has this many columns, so I frequently use a `SELECT` statement to look at 34 of the fields that I mentally categorize as 'group 1' and 12 fields that I categorize as 'group 2'.

Would I face a performance hit on reads/writes if I split this table into two tables, one with 34 fields and another with 12 fields.

Both would have the same AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY so that they could be joined on the PRIMARY key if I need to look at at 46 fields at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a 1:1 mandatory relationship then you don't add much value by splitting the table. There are cases were 1:0..1 relations are best as separate tables though.

And your keys would go out of synch quickly. Assuming you'll insert into both tables in a single transaction, a failure on the first insert would generate a gap that doesn't happen on the 2nd table.

If you had an AUTO_INCREMENT on one table and used [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), then you lose the ability to do multiple row INSERTs

The KISS principle applies...

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.  I never looked at it from the point of view of a gap that occurs between inserting in table 1 and table 2.  I will keep it simple (stupid) heh.

Answer (score 6):

> It's hard to look at a table that has this many columns, so I
>   frequently use a SELECT statement to look at 34 of the fields that I
>   mentally categorize as 'group 1' and 12 fields that I categorize as
>   'group 2'.

[Create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to give an answer without knowing what the columns are.  If the table is properly designed (normalized properly), then having many columns isn't a bad thing.  You can use views as suggested, or you can just select the columns that you need to see based on the reason you are doing a query.

My guess, though, is that if we saw the columns, we'd find some cases of normalization issues since you already naturally want to see only part of them.  That's just a guess, though, not a design rule or anything like that.